# Seismicity associated with post glacial rebound

Tags: seismology, seismic

Allied to the question: *[Why is relative sea-level falling in Hudson Bay?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/why-is-relative-sea-level-falling-in-hudson-bay)*, where the surviving answers mention post glacial rebound.

Is seismicity associated with post glacial rebound and if so what is the frequency of quakes (number of quakes per time period) and their magnitudes?

Comment: searching for isostatic eartquakes might be helpful when finding information about this.

Comment: Relevant paper: https://doi.org/10.1134/S000143381907003X They say that "the nature of current seismicity of Fennoscandia is determined by tectonic stresses caused by both the global effect of the northwestern uplifting lithospheric plate under the Norwegian Sea (a constant source of tectonic stress accumulation) and local tectonic uplifts (the north coast of Norway) or lowerings (the Swedish coast of the Gulf of Bothnia), rather than by postglacial stresses."